# How do I invite someone to a meeting using google apps calendar when I am not subscribed to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am using the google apps spreadsheet APIs to send emails to people with a calendar invite. However, I am not subscribed to other people's calendar, hence cannot directly send calendar invites (they only work for calendars I own or am subscribed to). My requirement is to send emails to people from a spreadsheet with calendar invites, I can get the email part done, parsing of the email done, but cannot embed a calendar invite (either directly from calendar APIs or through gmail APIs embedding calendar).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The account you're using, is it an Apps Super Admin?

If so, it has access to all calendars on the domain and the default main calendar ID for all users is their email address. You would have full read/write access to all the calendars this way regardless of any sharing by the end user(s). You can also add all users calendars to the account and they'll appear under 'My Calendars'.

[More details here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765).

Comment: Well, the calendars are not in my domain. Imagine I am hosting an event which had a signup sheet where everyone inserted their gmail id. So they are out-in-the wild gmail accounts of users I got. I want to invite them to an event I am hosting. I can do that by typing all the gmail ids in a calendar invite from calendar.google.com, but since I already have a spreadsheet with the gmails, I want to create a google apps script that runs on the google spreadsheet and sends a calendar invite via email. Hope that clarifies the problem a bit ?